# try finally mystery

Tags: c#, try-catch, finally

Consider,

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fun());
        }

        static int fun()
        {
            int i = 0;
            try
            {
                i = 1;
                return i;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                i = 2;
                return i;
            }
            finally
            {
                i = 3;
            }
        }
```

The sample code outputs "1". but the value of i is changed to 3 in finally block. Why wasn't the value of 'i' changed to 3?

Thank you,

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421797/what-really-happens-in-a-try-return-x-finally-x-null-statement

Comment: @Joe - I searched SO. But i wasn't able to find. Thanks.

Comment: @mahesh, just click the ling Joe provided in his comment.

Comment: @Mark - I meant "before posting this question, i searched SO".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider this code- I think the code explains what you are thinking, and how you can make what you think should happen actually happen:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(fun(ref counter)); // Prints 1
    Console.WriteLine(counter); // Prints 3
}        

static int fun(ref int counter)
{
  try
  {
      counter = 1;
      return counter;
  }
  finally
  {
      counter = 3;
  }
}
```

With this code you return 1 from the method, but you also set the counter variable to 3, which you can access from outside the method.

Answer (score 7):

You have to remember that finally executes after everything else in the try and catch.  Place the return statement after the try/catch/finally statement to have it return 3.

Comment: We can't return from finally because it gives the error "Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause"

Comment: @Steve - Kevin modified his answer

Answer (score 3):

I imagine if you use a reference type instead of a value type you'd get different behavior.

Comment: True, but the real question is: at what point in a try/catch/finally does the return value get pushed on the stack for non-reference parameters?

Comment: +1. I think that is a very good point. I wish I had put that in my answer too!

Answer (score 2):

When you said "return i"... C# puts that return value in a temporary holding area (memory) and  then runs your 'finally' code... if the finally block was able to modify that value, it would defeat the safety/finalism of the finally block.

It's like a using statement with a return inside... the "Dispose" is still going to happen, AFTER the return (so to speak).

Comment: +1 Thats it.  I was about to post simply "Because the return has already happened" but this answer is pretty much there.

Answer (score 1):

### Finally is always executed

Your code always executes finally no matter if an exception was thrown or not. So your code should actually be:

```
try
{
    i = 1;
}
catch
{
    i = 2;
}
finally
{
    i = 3;
}
return i;
```

But in this trivial case finally block won't make much sense. Because we will always return 3 no matter what happened before that.

### Finally is used to release resources

`finally` block should normally be used when you have to release some system resources allocated within `try` block (ie. openning a DB connection an reading data in `try` block and closing it in `finally`). So they will always get released no matter if there was an exception or not. In this case it doesn't make much sense to use `finally` block.

Comment: I would ask person that voted my answer -1 to clarify their decision.