# Return in the Finally Block... Why not?

Tags: .net, try-catch-finally

As MSDN [mentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VB.RETURN%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true):

> The code in a Finally block runs after
>   a Return statement in a Try or Catch
>   block is encountered, but before that
>   Return statement executes. In this
>   situation, a Return statement in the
>   Finally block executes before the
>   initial Return statement. This gives a
>   different return value. To prevent
>   this potentially confusing situation,
>   avoid using Return statements in
>   Finally blocks.

As I didn't understand a lot from this note, I'll take an example (VB.NET, I think in C# is the situation is similar):

```
Try
    HugeOp()
    Return "OK"
Catch
    Return "NOK"
Finally
    Return "Finally"
End Try
```

Now, **why should be this illegal** in both C# and VB.NET?

Comment: what happens when you run it?

Comment: As I always recommend, just make a small test program to emulate the case and see for yourself.

Comment: it is ***illegal*** in C# (edit: and, it seems, VB)

Comment: @serhio: so there's your answer

Comment: @Marc Gravell: this is illegal in VB.NET, as well.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: The question was ***WHY*** this

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on the question being asked. Did you run the code? What did it return?

Comment: @serhio ah, then MSDN is confusing ; a better remark in MSDN would be "avoid using Return statements in Finally blocks, else your code won't compile"; I have annotated MSDN to this effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What really happens in a try { return x; } finally { x = null; } statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421797/what-really-happens-in-a-try-return-x-finally-x-null-statement)

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦: Why do in general mention phrases like "*avoid* using Return out of the method blocks, else your code won't compile"? Instead a phrase like `The .NET compilers (C#, VB) does not allow the using of "Return" in the finally locks, because of bla bla...` would be more appropriate...

Comment: @Matt Ellen: 2 different questions

Comment: @serhio - the note in MSDN *does* give reasoning. My point is that it isn't an "avoid" thing (which sounds like a recommendation); it **will not work**

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦: Ya ya, that was my point. But your "better remark" still keeps the "avoid" word... )

Comment: An interesting side note: this is *not* illegal in JavaScript. `function m()
{
  try { return 1; } finally { return 2; }
}` a call to `m()` will return 2.  Implementing that was a real pain for the development team.  It's also legal in Java.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's illegal because when you reach the `Finally` block, the value to return is already defined ("OK" if everything went well, "NOK" if an exception was caught). If you were able to return a different value from the `Finally` block, this value would *always* be returned, whatever the outcome of the instructions above. It just wouldn't make sense...

Comment: thank you. So "Finally" should be the return value. Made illegal to "de-confuse" the code.

Comment: No, the return value is set *before* the return statement is executed. Inbetween those two things, the finally block is executed. It therefore makes no sense to have a return statement in a finally block. It doesn't make sense to say that finally "should" be the return value because it doesn't makes sense for finally to *have* a return value.

Comment: @izb: In other words, in my success case, the compiler takes "OK" as return value, executes the Finally block, then takes the "OK" and effectively returns it?

Comment: The specification could define the behavior of `return` in a finally statement however it likes. It could return the old return value, the new return value or be illegal. Any if these behaviors is possible, and they chose to make it illegal. And I agree with that decision.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the return value being set already. You could delete the first two returns and you'd get the same error,.

Comment: @usr, if you have a better explanation, feel free to post an answer ;)

Comment: It is not required to post an answer in order to point out a flaw in an existing one.

Comment: @usr, indeed. To give a more useful answer to your comment, what you said is true, but consider this: it makes sense to forbid `return` in `finally` if you already returned something in the `try` or `catch`; it *could* be allowed when you *didn't return anything* in the `try` or `catch`, but it would be inconsistent. I think the language designers just wanted to avoid the inconsistency. Of course, it's just my guess; to know the true reason, you'd have to ask the language designers themselves ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is in the question. It's illegal because it's confusing. It's not intuitive which value will be returned. If it's illegal, you are forced to write code where the flow is much clearer.

Comment: "confusing", "intuitive", but really what should be the return here after the compiler rules? Is it always "Finally"?

Comment: Looks like the compiler rules state it's illegal and shouldn't compile. So the question what it does return makes no sense.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: read the note I posted. "This gives a different return value."

Comment: You're note is obviously inaccurate and doesn't describe the behavior of either C# or VB.net. That's why @MarcGravell suggested that the documentation should be updated to be consistent with the actual behavior of the compiler.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I am not sure if in Visual Studio this kind of "Error" could not be "downgraded" to a Warning...

Comment: Making it a warning would violate the spec. "8.9.4 The return statement" - "It is a compile-time error for a return statement to appear in a finally block" (From the C# specification)

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about this, I'm running VS2010 and does not allow a Return in the finally block. here is the code I compiled

```
Public Class Class1
   Public Shared Function test() As String
      Try
         Return "OK"
      Catch ex As Exception
         Return "Catch"
      Finally
         test = "Finally"
      End Try
   End Function
End Class
```

I compiled the DLL to view the MSIL it looked rather interesting the above code basically gets refactored to this:

```
Public Class Class2
   Public Shared Function test() As String
      Try
         Try
            test = "OK"
         Catch ex As Exception
            test = "Catch"
         End Try
      Finally
         test = "Finally"
      End Try

      Return test
   End Function
End Class
```

and testing this out, the MSIL for the above two classes is exactly the same.

Comment: so, finally, you found a way to return in finally block in Visual Basic, using the function's name, even if confusing, there is a way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `return` statements aren't allowed in `finally` blocks ultimately comes down to the point/ goal of those structures.

`Finally` blocks are special blocks of code intended to always run start to finish, **after** some previous control structure has finished executing; they're primarily for "cleanup"-type code.

If we take the code provided:

```vbnet
Try
    HugeOp()
    Return "OK"
Catch
    Return "NOK"
Finally
    Return "Finally"
End Try
```

The `Finally` block will be **executed *after* the `Return` from either the `Try` or `Catch`**.

This does kind of mean that having a `Return` there would "always return the same thing", but it's more than that– **a `Return` *already* happened** in the current procedure! What should that instruction even mean? Where are we returning to?

In the general case, a `Return` makes no sense within a `Finally` because having a statement that transfers control outside of these blocks is 1) antithetical to their purpose, and 2) hard to even conceptualize, since `Finally` blocks break the "standard" control flow when they run since they come after the `Return` of some previous control structure.

In C#, `goto`s are disallowed in `finally` blocks for essentially the same reason: external control transfer is just off limits within `finally` by design.

---

JavaScript can serve as an example here of how confusing things could be without this rule: [in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_finally_block), `finally` blocks execute immediately *before* a control-flow statement (e.g. `return`) in `try`/ `catch`, but *do* allow `return`s inside themselves– which will overshadow (override) the `return` inside the `try`/ `catch`, if it exists.

I'd argue there's no resolution to this problem that's *not* confusing, other than just outright disallowing it.