# Server side validation message does not show inside a PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a custom Validation attribute, to check PhoneNumbers:

```
public class PhoneNumberIsValidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string phoneNumberRaw = (string)value;
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{6,8}$");
            Match match = regex.Match(phoneNumberRaw);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I annotate my model:

```
public class MyModel
{   
    [DisplayName("Override phone number")]
    [PhoneNumberIsValid("Test")]
    public string OverridePhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And in **myView**:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OverridePhoneNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OverridePhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control input-text", @maxlength = GlobalConstants.MaxLengthForPhoneNumber /*, @type = "url" */})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OverridePhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Everything works as expected, as demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sqHesW)

### Here is the problem

*Unfortunately I cannot demonstrate the issue on the fiddle.*

If I put the `input` inside **_MyPartialView**, and call it from **MyView** as shown below:

```
@Html.Partial("path/_MyPartialView", Model)
```

Then the `ValidationMessage` does not show under the `input` box as shown below:

[image]

This problem only happen when:

1. The input is inside a *PartialView*
2. When the error message comes from the server (client-side error messages are displayed correctly)

*I got this error with both .NET Framework 4.6.1 and 4.7.2.

Comment: [Illegal `return` in `finally block`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788134/return-in-the-finally-block-why-not)

Comment: @Hooman Bahreini: You should have gotten the compilation error `error CS0157: Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause`

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo when copy pasting the code

Comment: @HoomanBahreini: Did you try to put the `@Html.TextBoxFor()` inside the `<p>` tag?

Comment: I believe this might be a [bug](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/304)