# Is it possible to change the return value in a finally clause in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, return

**Assume that you have a C# method with a `return` statement inside a `try` block. Is it possible to modify the return value in the `finally` block?**

The obvious approach, using `return` in the `finally` block, won't work:

```
String Foo()
{
    try
    {
        return "A";
    }
    finally
    {
        // Does not compile: "Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause"
        return "B";
    }
}
```

Interestingly, this *can* be done in VB: `Return` inside `Finally` is forbidden, but we can abuse the fact that (probably for reasons of backwards compatibility) VB still allows the return value to be modified by assigning it to the method name:

```vb
Function Foo() As String    ' Returns "B", really!
    Try
        Return "A"
    Finally
        Foo = "B"
    End Try
End Function
```

---

Notes:

1. Note that I ask this question *purely* out of scientific curiosity; obviously, code like that is highly error-prone and confusing and should never be written.
2. Note that I am *not* asking about `try { var x = "A"; return x; } finally { x = "B"; }`. I am aware that this doesn't change the return value and [I understand why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421797/87698). I'd like to know if there *are* ways to change the return value set inside the try block by means of a finally block.

Comment: Stop abusing VB.NET - it gets enough abuse already!

Comment: Just because you *can* do this in VB does not mean you *should*!

Comment: Stop using VB.NET - it gets enough use already!

Comment: @MattWilko: I never claimed that you should -- see the last sentence of my question.

Comment: I wouldn't call this an abuse of VB, it's more like VB abuses programmers and leads them down the wrong track with it's weird ad-hoc rules and inconsistencies.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Assume that you have a C# method with a return statement inside a try block. Is it possible to modify the return value in the finally block?

No.

You can however modify the return value *outside the finally block*:

```
static int M()
{
    try
    {
        try
        { 
            return 123;
        }
        finally
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return 456;
    }
}
```

Just because there was originally a "return 123" does not mean that the method will return 123, if that's what your question is actually getting at. This method returns 456.

Comment: Very interesting. It appears the only exemption rule is when an exception is thrown inside the `finally` block.

Comment: @BradM: You are correct. More generally: there are only three possible control flows within a `finally` block: (1) never leave, (2) leave normally, or (3) leave via thrown exception. Other control flows like `return`, `goto`, `break`, `continue`, `yield return`, `yield break` and `await` are either not legal in a finally block, or are only allowed if they jump to a location *within* the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

The VB.NET version is abusing a vestigial construct from the VB6 era in which you return a value by assigning the value to the name of the function.

What would be really interesting to know is if there is a difference in the IL produced when using a standard `return` statement as opposed to `myFunc = "B"`, as the `try...catch...finally` semantics would seem to dictate that it would be impossible to alter the value returned by a `return` statement.

Comment: `MyFunc = "B"` doesn't Return so the IL will not be the same

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following to approach the same effect:

```
private string myFunction()
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        //..
        result = "something";
    }
    finally
    {
        result = "something else";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again. The question begins "assume you have a return statement in a try block". Where is the return statement in your try block?

Comment: read my answer again.. ".. to approach the SAME EFFECT".. it is an alternative, not a solution, because it's not possible. no reason to vote down..

Answer (score -1):

A close analogy with the cited VB approach would be assigning a revised value to the variable used by `return` (which has the benefit of conserving a single point of return of control):

```
string returnResult;

try
{
    returnResult = "A";
}
finally
{
    returnResult = "B";
}

return returnResult;
```

Comment: Read the question again. The question begins "assume you have a return statement in a try block". Where is the return statement in your try block?

Comment: There's nothing wrong on SO with telling the user "Don't do it like that, do it like this instead" - just giving them the answer to their question isn't always the right thing to do if what they're trying to do is wrong.

Comment: The last paragraph of the question indicates that the original poster is aware that it is bad style.