# Is this a valid object disposal code pattern in method with return?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I noticed the following object disposal code pattern in a C# project and I was wondering if it's acceptable (although it works).

```
public object GetData()
{
    object obj;

    try
    {
        obj = new Object();

        // code to populate SortedList

        return obj;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            obj.Dispose();
            obj = null;
        }
    }
}
```

For this example, I'm using a general 'object' instead of the actual IDisposable class in the project.

I know that the 'finally' block will be executed every time, even when the value is returned, but would it affect the return value (or would it be a new object instance) in any way since the object is being set to null (for what seems like object disposal and GC purposes).

**Update 1:**

I tried the following snippet and the return object is non-null, although the local object is set to null, so it works, which is a bit strange considering some of the comments below:

```
public StringBuilder TestDate()
{
    StringBuilder sb;

    try
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());

        return sb;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        sb = null;
    }
}
```

Btw, I'm using C# 4.0.

P.S. I'm just reviewing this project code. I'm not the original author.

**Update 2:**

Found the answer to this mystery [1]. The finally statement is executed, but the return value isn't affected (if set/reset in the finally block).

[1] [What really happens in a try { return x; } finally { x = null; } statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421797/what-really-happens-in-a-try-return-x-finally-x-null-statement)

Answer (score 5):

This code will compile fine (assuming that you are not actually using an `Object` but something that implements `IDisposable`), but it probably won't do what you want it to do. In C#, you don't get a new object without a `new`; this code will return a reference to an object that has already been disposed, and depending on the object and what Dispose() actually does, trying to use a disposed object may or may not crash your program.

I assume the idea is to create an object, do some stuff with it, then return the object if successful or null (and dispose the object) on failure. If so, what you should do is:

```
try {
    obj = new MyClass();
    // ... do some stuff with obj
    return obj;
}
catch {
    if(obj != null) obj.Dispose();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Even so, that's not considered a good practice. An IDisposable method should be created and killed within the same scope.

Comment: Agree with @dcastro. If you don't create and dispose of a disposable object in the same scope, or at most the same isolated module, you are opening a big can of worms.

Comment: @dcastro what exactly " not considered a good practice"? Disposable objects should be disposed by owners. In case of transferring ownership (similar for `File.OpenText`) owner changes in case of successful completion, but in case of error method still owns the object and must dispose it...

Comment: Well, I would consider the exampled pointed out by John Saunders an exception, because the method is solely responsible for creating the object. If thats what you consider transferring ownership, then I'd agree with you.

Comment: @dcastro and T.C. - I've changed the sample to reflect ownership transfer on success. Feel free to revert if it was not the intention of the sample.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I think the code before the change was generally better, but should use `finally` rather than `catch` since there is no pretext of "handling" the exception--it should be allowed to bubble up unchanged. Using a catch-and-rethrow can have some undesired effects.

Comment: @supercat / T.C. - not enough coffee :) - yes somehow I read it as `finally`... your code is indeed fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: The semantically-best approach is start by putting a reference to the `Disposable` object into a variable which, if non-null, the `finally` block will `Dispose`.  Once it's clear that things will succeed, copy that variable to another one and clear it so the `finally` block won't `Dispose` it.  Alternatively, have a `bool Success=false;` variable and set it to `true` just before the `return`; then have the `finally` dispose of things if `Success` hasn't been set.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using the `using` statement achieves the same result as that, and is the standard practice

```
public int A()
{
    using(IDisposable obj = new MyClass())
    {
        //...
        return something;
    }
}
```

I would, however, advise against returning your IDisposable object.
When you dispose of an object, it is supposed to be considered "unusable". And so, why return it?

If the object's lifetime needs to be longer than the method `A`'s lifetime, consider having the calling method `B` instantiate the object, and pass it as a parameter to method `A`.
In this case, method `B`would be the one using the `using` statement, inside which it would call `A`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning an IDisposable object, then it is the responsibility of your caller to dispose of it:

```
public IDisposable MakeDisposableObject()
{
    return new SqlConnection(""); // or whatever
}
```

caller:

```
using (var obj = MakeDisposableObject())
{
}
```

It makes less than no sense for your method to dispose of an object and then return it. The disposed object will be of no value to the caller. In general, referencing a disposable object which has been disposed should produce an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations.

That code wouldn't compile because `object` doesn't have a `.Dispose()` method.

Why wouldn't you use `IDisposable`?

Why would you dispose of an object that is being returned, since returning you would return an object for the purpose of some other code to use it. The concept of "disposing" of something is to give it a chance to clean up after itself and its used, un-managed resources. If you are returning an object that is supposed to be used elsewhere, but has unmanaged resources that you want to clean up before the object gets used anywhere else, then you shuld really have 2 separate objects. One to load some data that would be disposable, and another object that would contain the usable loaded content that you want to pass around. An example of this would be something like stream readers in the .NET framework. You would normally `new` a stream reader, read it into a `byte[]` or some other data object, `.Dispose()` the stream reader, then `return` the `byte[]`. The "loader" that has some resources to dispose of in a timely fashion is separate from the object containing the "loaded" data that can be used without needing to be disposed.

Comment: As I mentioned, for this example, I'm using a general 'object' instead of the actual IDisposable class in the project.