# return in try-catch's finally block in java. Is there any good point in this example?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm not familiar with java and I've been recently looking at some code written by some colleagues that's baffling me. Here's the gist of it:

```
public response newStuff(//random data inside) {
    try {
       response or = //gives it a value
       log.info(or.toString());
       return or;
    }
    catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there really any point in adding a finally block here? Couldn't I just add the return null inside the catch block, which would execute the same behavior, or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, don't put `return` statements in `finally` blocks. Please.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've never seen or even thought about doing this. Wouldn't after calling return, you jump into the finally block again?

Comment: Your code will always return `null`. Putting `return` in `catch` is not the same thing as putting it in `finally`.

Comment: Go read this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: @RohitJain I was thinking this at first too, however his `try` block ends with `return or;`, so the `finally` block would never execute unless he enters a `catch` block, right?

Comment: @nhgrif finally always executes, whether you catch an expection or not. The method cannot return without first going through finally.

Comment: @nhgrif Actually, the new return value in finally block will overwrite the existing return value.

Comment: Hmm.  Okay, good to know.  I'm not a `try-catch-finally` master by any measure.

Comment: *finally* blocks **always** execute, there's no point using a return there as the method will always return the same thing.

Comment: It is strange to me that the designers of Java, JavaScript, Python, etc, all allowed a return inside a finally. It seems to add no additional power to the language while simultaneously inserting a terrible "gotcha" situation. The equivalent code would be illegal in C#.

Comment: @EricLippert I didn't even know that also Python had this! However I have **never** seen it used, and not even *mentioned* anywhere, while I *did* see it used in few Java programs.

Comment: @AngelRodríguez you can have logic in a finally - it needn't always return the same thing - granted the example above does.

Comment: I read the title as Try/Catch (is) finally in Java. :D

Comment: Try/Catch/Finally are almost always a bad idea. Especially when you put a return somewhere inside it.

Comment: @Phil sure, i was just pointing to the sample code provided... bad English sorry...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning from a finally block in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421797/what-really-happens-in-a-try-return-x-finally-x-null-statement

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Is there really any point in adding a finally block here?

The answer to this is a resounding "no": putting a `return` statement in the `finally` block is a very bad idea.

> I just add the return null inside the catch block, which would execute the same behavior, or am I wrong?

It wouldn't match the original behavior, but that's a good thing, because it would fix it. Rather than returning `null` unconditionally the way the original code does, the code with the `return` inside the `catch` block would return `null` only on errors. In other words, the value returned in the `try` branch would be returned to the caller unless there is an exception.

Moreover, if you add `return null` *after* the `catch` block, you would see the correct effect of returning `null` on exception. I would go even further, and put a single `return` in the method, like this:

```
response or = null;
try {
   or = //gives it a value
   log.info(or.toString());
} catch ( Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return or;
```

Comment: Furthermore, I'd add that, `response` doesn't follow naming conventions. Also, I would highly advise against `catch(Exception e)`

Comment: Thanks. I'll make some changes to the code then. I didn't want to rush into making changes in case I was the local idiot.

Comment: Putting the `return` inside the catch block wouldn't yield the same behavior in case `e.printStackTrace()` would throw an exception.

Comment: @Flow does `e.printStackTrace()` ever throw anything (where `e` is non-null, as it would be here)?

Comment: `printStackTrace()` uses I/O, which could cause an exception.

Comment: @Flow in the case that `e.printStackTrace()` throws an exception, then you will not reach the return statement that is after the try...catch either.

Comment: Exactly, if you want to keep the semantic of the code presented in the question, i.e. never throw an `Exception` but return `null` instead, you have to put the `return or;` in the answer above in a `finally` block. I don't think that this answer is correct otherwise.

Comment: @Flow The OP does not want to mimic the semantic of the code that he posted - quite to the contrary, he is questioning its validity.

Comment: That is also correct. But op asked `I just add the return null inside the catch block, which would execute the same behavior, or am I wrong?` and you answered `You are absolutely right.` which is wrong. This [blalassadri answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19498813/194894) and even if the return in the finally would not override the return in the try block, it wouldn't yield the same semantic.

Comment: @Flow I edited the answer to explain how moving the `return` statement out of the `finally` block changes the semantic. Thanks!

Comment: @Cruncher I would also add that a variable named 'or' doesn't follow any naming convention system or scheme that I have ever encountered or can imagine.

Answer (score 23):

Actually, no. Finally is (nearly) always run, no matter what the result in the try-catch block; so this block **always** returns `null`. Here, look at this example:

```
public class Finally {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(finallyTester(true));
    System.out.println(finallyTester(false));
}

public static String finallyTester(boolean succeed) {
    try {
        if(succeed) {
            return "a";
        } else {
            throw new Exception("b");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "b";
    } finally {
        return "c";
    }
  }

}
```

It will print "c" both times.

The above mentioned exception to the rule would be if the thread itself is interrupted; e.g. by `System.exit()`. This is however a rare thing to happen.

Comment: +1 as it truly demonstrates what Netbeans warns of `return in finally block discards unhandled exceptions`

Answer (score 5):

The `finally` is always executed no matter what, and normally can be used to close sessions, etc. 
Don't put returns inside a finally block.

Comment: "the finally is always executed" - did you try `System.exit()` ? :)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a very bad practice. In this case your code **will always** return `null`.

The `finally` block is called last after the `try-catch` block runs. No matter if the `try` finished or the `exception` block was called. In this case, no matter which path of code is ran, you will always return null.
In the "normal" case where you put the `return null` after the finally there's indeed a chance to return something (either from the `try` or from the `catch` block) and if no flow yields a return object, you fall back to the `return null`, but you don't always return null.

Answer (score 4):

I've read that a lot of people simply answer "don't use `return` in a finally block", without any explanation. Well, actually the code you posted is a good example where a `return` in a `finally` block is causing massive confusion. Even the, as of time of writing this, [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19498655/1), **got it wrong**. Your code will always execute the `return null;` as last command, [even if there is an Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740/194894).

But I can think of a situation where a `return` in a `finally` block actually makes sense. It appears to me that the goal of the author of your code was that the method **never throws a `Throwable`, but returns `null` instead**. This can actually be achieved if you modify the code like this:

```
public Result newStuff() {
    Result res = null;
    try {
       res = someMethod();
       log.info(res.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        return res;
    }
}
```

But note that this will not call `printStackTrace()` on `Error`s and `Throwable`s which are not `Exception`s.

Answer (score 3):

The "Finally" block will execute regardless of whether the "Catch" fires or not.  So the behaviour is different than if you just put "return null" in the Catch block.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no `return` statement in the finally block,remove `return`.

Answer (score 2):

The need of finally block is where when you have such a code that should always be executed like you want to close your input stream or you want to close any connection etc.Just googled about this you will easily find the example for this.

In your case you are writing a method where you are returning something in try block and at the end you are writing finally block where you are returning null.I don't see any use of finally block here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally block is used if you want to execute some statements even if code in try block or catch block generates an exception or not. But as you are using return in try block then there is no significance of putting a return in finally block. You can return directly from catch block and can remove finally block.

Answer (score 1):

First understand why we need this three blocks in simple words for beginners.

1)try block: If you have doubt that your code will lead to an exception then put in try block

2)catch block: If exception arises then a piece of code you need to perform should be written in this block

3)finally block: If you want your piece of code to be executed no matters if exception arises or not then we go for finally block. Mainly this block is use for releasing resources.
For example:

```
try{
   Connection conn=//something;
   //some code for database operations

}catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace()
}finally{
      conn=null;
}
```

No matter what is result, you have to make connection as null because it is heavy object which if referenced will create load on database as only few connection objects are available.
Hence best way to keep them in finally block.

In your case, return null in finally block is bad approach as it will always return null although exception arises or not.