# File Stream not return after closing it in finally block C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have download files by returning as stream like below using WCF rest service.

```
 Stream stream = null;          
            var directoryInformation = CommonServices.Utility.DirectoryHelper.GetTempFolderRootLocation();
            string newFolderPath = directoryInformation + "\\Attachments\\" + Guid.NewGuid();
            try
            {

                Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolderPath);
                DataSet getDocumentContent = GetDocumentContent(engagementId, documentId);
                var fileName = getDocumentContent.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fullname"] as string;
                var byteData= getDocumentContent.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FilestreamContent"] as byte[];
                string fullPath = newFolderPath + "\\" + fileName;        
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    if (byteData != null)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(byteData,0,byteData.Length);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }

                    if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
                    {
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("content-disposition","inline; filename=" + fileName);
                    }
                }
                stream = File.OpenRead(fullPath);
                return stream;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                return null;
            }
```

The above code works perfectly and can download the file in browser. But i have to delete the file after return the stream. So i have try to close and delete the file including the directory in finally block like below

```
   finally
            {
                if (stream != null) stream.Close();
                Directory.Delete(newFolderPath, true);
            }
```

**Full Method code**

```
 public Stream DownloadAttachment(string engagementId, string documentId)
        {
            Stream stream = null;          
            var directoryInformation = CommonServices.Utility.DirectoryHelper.GetTempFolderRootLocation();
            string newFolderPath = directoryInformation + "\\Attachments\\" + Guid.NewGuid();
            try
            {

                Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolderPath);
                DataSet getDocumentContent = GetDocumentContent(engagementId, documentId);
                var fileName = getDocumentContent.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fullname"] as string;
                var byteData= getDocumentContent.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FilestreamContent"] as byte[];
                string fullPath = newFolderPath + "\\" + fileName;        
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    if (byteData != null)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(byteData,0,byteData.Length);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }

                    if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
                    {
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("content-disposition","inline; filename=" + fileName);
                    }
                }
                stream = File.OpenRead(fullPath);
                return stream;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                return null;
            }
           finally
            {
                if (stream != null) stream.Close();
                Directory.Delete(newFolderPath, true);
            }
        }
```

After adding this code file is not downloaded in client.Is there any way to delete the file?Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Did you add this finally block at the end of the mentioned method? If so, `Close` will dispose the same stream you're trying to return.

Comment: could you please look at the source code.i have updated my question by adding the full method

Comment: You're trying to return a fileStream to a deleted file?

Comment: actuall i have return stream after reading a file from server so browser will download this file based on the content type. But after return the stream i have to delete that file. When i try to delete this file without close it shows an exception file is used by another process

Comment: You can't return a `FileStream` to a file which you want to delete because the `FileStream` will hold a handle to that file. Why not return a byte[] with the file instead?

Comment: See how try catch finally with return statement works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421797/what-really-happens-in-a-try-return-x-finally-x-null-statement)

Comment: but the code is working fine and downloaded the file in browser. The only pblm is when i try to close in finally i think the stream get clear

Comment: It gets disposed when you call `stream.Close()`. You need to re-think what you're doing.

Comment: is there any way to achieve the download and delete functionality together?

Comment: Do you have to return a `Stream`?

Comment: Yes.I have to return the stream else it will not download the file in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the file in `OperationContext.OperationCompleted` as shown in http://devdump.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/disposing-return-values/

```
OperationContext clientContext = OperationContext.Current;
clientContext.OperationCompleted += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
          if (stream != null) stream.Close();
          Directory.Delete(newFolderPath, true);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to this.

```
public void DownloadAttachment(string engagementId, string documentId, Action<Stream> processFile)
```

and instead of returning the stream call the processFile Action

```
processFile(stream);
```

This way you're not leaving the method in order to process the file. You will need to restructure the calling code in order to process the file though.